# Динамическая структура с помощью flex или grid

Tags: css, sass

Структура -

```
|.sidebar|.content|
```

`.sidebar` - максимум `300px`, минимум `200px`.

`.content` - максимум `800px`.

`.sidebar` прижат к левой стороне экрана. Если ширина меньше меньше `1100px`, то `.sidebar` начинает сжиматься до `200px`. При меньше `1000px` `.sidebar` должен уехать за левую границу экрана и при этом по событию он должен выезжать с максимальной шириной сдвигая (не уменьшая) `.content`.

Когда экран больше `1100px`, то `.content` должен быть по середине экрана.

Суть вопроса к опытным верстальщикам - можно ли сделать такое очень просто с помощью `css`, допускается `flex` и `grid`? Я частично сделал на `flex`+ `@media` но дойдя до выдвижения `.sidebar`, решил что лучше посоветоваться, возможно с помощью `grid` подобное делать более правильно?. Когда смотришь  примеры крутых верстальщиков, они подобные вещи делают в пару строчек кода,  но у меня его уже очень много и все равно не получается сделать все.

```css
.container  {
    width: 100%;

    display: inline-flex;


    justify-items: center;
    justify-content:space-between;
}



.center {
    max-width: 800px;

    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;

    background: tomato;
}

.left{
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 200px;

    width: auto;
    height: 300px;

    flex-grow: 1;

    background: pink;

    transition: left .5s;

    position: relative;
}
.right{
    flex-grow: 1;
}

@media (min-width:1400px){
    body{
        background: rosybrown;
    }
    .container{
        justify-content:start;
    }
    .left {
        max-width: none;
        min-width: 0;
    }
}


.sidebar{
    max-width:300px;
    min-height:200px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background: yellowgreen;


}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Событие и его обработку для появления сайдбара придется уже самому добавить.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  max-width: 1100px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

aside {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
}

section {
  background-color: black;
  flex-basis: 800px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  main {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  aside {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  
  section {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside></aside>
  <section></section>
</main>
```

Или вот то же самое на гридах:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  max-width: 1100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 300px) 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

aside {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

section {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  main {
    overflow: hidden;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }

  aside {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside></aside>
  <section></section>
</main>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но  к моему сожалению, это совершенно не то,  что я описал в вопросе.

Comment: Хм, а можно тогда вторую попытку объяснения? Только что перечитал и вроде как не вижу чем это не то.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko Привет Александр. С Новым годом!  Успехов и творческих удач.(+) Рад снова увидеть твою активность. Давненько ты не включался на полную мощь.

Comment: Действительно я не сказал что .sidebar, тогда когда не убран заграницу экрана, должен быть прижат к левой стороне экрана.